# why wont matlab read command ReadData3d?

Tags: matlab

i have the following code to read biomedical data

```
info =mha_read_header('VSD.Brain.XX.O.MR_T2.54230.mha');
V = mha_read_volume(info);

[V1,info1] = ReadData3D('VSD.Brain.XX.O.MR_T2.54230.mha');
```

but i get the following error:

```
Unrecognized function or variable 'mha_read_header'.

Error in image_project (line 4)
info =mha_read_header('VSD.Brain.XX.O.MR_T2.54230.mha');
```

or the vive versa for the ReadData3D. and i do not get it. Of course i have downloaded and opened the functions next to the main programm.

Comment: You say that the functions are "opened". Does that mean they are saved in a folder in the [Search Path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html)?

Comment: @beaker I mean that i have opened them in windows next to the main one and I also have them in the same folder, all of them

Comment: And `which mha_read_header` returns the location of the function? (Note that having the functions open in windows is irrelevant to being able to call them.)

Comment: i dont understand you. here is the link:https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29344-read-medical-data-3d?fbclid=IwAR23Bsun4joKCRreoFQ52_pScZ_Mn-EtUbT_l26piNhfI3hjh-gCzdaEC2I

Comment: I was asking you to type the command `which mha_read_header` in your command window.

Comment: oh ok. It outputs:'mha_read_header' not found. but i find it very weird, although i am a newbie in matlab